# Proper positioning (Screen width & height)

Tags: actionscript-3, resolution

A little lost here. I've got two movieclips. I want one on the far left (out of reach until the user hovers over their left side of the screen) and one on the far right. I've tried playing with [Screen](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Screen.html), [Capabilities](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html), and [stage](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html).

I don't know why, but apparently my resolution 1536 by 864?

```
trace("Screen x = " + Capabilities.screenResolutionX); //Screen x = 1536
trace("Screen y = " + Capabilities.screenResolutionY); //Screen y = 864
```

I don't want to set the position of the native window to what the difference of the stage's with and height is to screenResoltionX and Y just because that number seems so off to me. I'm on a monitor with it's current resolution at 1920 x 1080. The only thing I can think of is that I have my laptop set to display only on the monitor at this time with it's main screen inactive, yet the window appears on my monitor, so i'm assuming its picking up the values from my monitor .. and my laptop's screen has no where near that weird of a resolution. Anyone know where this is coming from? I've never seen this before. The same numbers return from stage.fullScreenWidth and stage.fullScreenHeight..

I'm using Adobe AIR 17.0 to build this. Building it with an opaque window. The current size of the stage is set to 1024 x 786.

Edit: I want these objects on the edges of the user's screen. I'm trying to get a grid that represents the entire bounds of the user's screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `Capabilities.screenResolutionX` & `Capabilities.screenResolutionY`,  it is reporting for the **primary display** (so if you have more than one monitor, regardless of which monitor your app is on, it will report back the primary monitor's resolution), and only at the time your application starts (so if you change resolution after the app starts Capabilities.screenResolutionX will not reflect the new screen resolution).

Here is a quote from the documentation: (emphasis mine)

> This property does not update with a user's screen resolution and instead only indicates the resolution at the time Flash Player or an Adobe AIR application started. **Also, the value only specifies the primary screen.**

For your purposes, it seems like it shouldn't matter what the screen resolution is.  Just use the `stage.stageWidth` & `stage.stageHeight` values since they reflect the boundaries of your actual app, regardless of which monitor it's on or if it's full screen, windowed, or scaled etc.

```
if(stage.mouseX < stage.stageWidth * 0.5){
    //mouse is on the left hand side of the application.
}
```

---

**EDIT**

Based off your comment, sounds like you need to do this:

When your app first runs, do this to make it responsive/liquid:

```
stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE
```

Then the `stage.stageWidth` and `stage.stageHeight` properties will reflect the actual window size.

You can maximize it through code with:

```
stage.nativeWindow.maximize();
```

You can listen for window sizing changes with:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, myResizeHandler);

function myResizeHandler(e:Event):void { 
    //stage.stageWidth & stage.stageHeight have changed
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I'm trying to be on the opposite edges of the user's screen. Running stage.stageWidth and stage.stageHeight only return the values I set in adobe flash cc for the stage. 1024x786.

Comment: You're wanting to move the actual application window?

Comment: Is your application full screen / maximized?

Comment: Yes, its a desktop application so I want the window to appear on the top left and adjust its size to take up the entire screen. Then I want to position those objects based on the new size so that they're off screen but accessible by an invisible object with a MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER event.

Comment: No, its not fullscreen and I'm trying to avoid that. This application is meant to replace explorer so that's why I want the far reaches of the entire desktop.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the quick reply, detail and edit.